# Сортировка или поиск по нескольким параметрам

Tags: c#, поиск, сортировка

У меня есть класс StationInfo со свойствами

```
public uint EnergyConsumption { get; private set; }
public uint CurrentEnergyAmount { get; private set; }
public uint NumRobotsNearStation { get; private set; }
public uint NumStationsAround { get; private set; }
```

я создаю массив типа `StationInfo`.

Мне нужно найти в этом массиве такой объект `StationInfo`, который удовлетворяет такому условию одновременно:

```
EnergyConsumption -> min
CurrentEnergyAmount -> max
NumRobotsNearStation -> max
NumStationsAround -> min
```

Пример с 2 аргументами:

```
{2,1}
{3,4}
{6,7}
{1,10}
{2, 15}
```

нужно найти среди объектов обьект со своими свойствами `{min, max}`

С такими условиями объектов нет, но есть объект, близкий к условию - `{2, 15}`

Есть ли в шарпах какое-то готовое средство для этого, а то неохото тратить время на написание алгоритма.

Comment: Эээ... Уточните задание. Что если минимум `EnergyConsumption` и максимум `CurrentEnergyAmount` приходятся на разные элементы?

Comment: Хм, всё равно непонятно. А чем `{2, 15}` лучше, чем `{1, 10}`? Каков точный критерий?

Comment: разница между min и max большая

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял условие, вам надо такое минимизировать следующую величину:

```
EnergyConsumption - CurrentEnergyAmount - NumRobotsNearStation + NumStationsAround
```

Если так, можно решить очевидным образом:

```
static int Evaluate(StationInfo info)
{
    return info.EnergyConsumption
         - info.CurrentEnergyAmount
         - info.NumRobotsNearStation
         + info.NumStationsAround;
}

var best = stations.OrderBy(Evaluate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Протестировал - шикарно работает! То, что нужно. Правда непонял, как вот эта штука работает: 
return info.EnergyConsumption - info.CurrentEnergyAmount - info.NumRobotsNearStation + info.NumStationsAround;

Обьясните пожалуста

Comment: Ну, это такая величина, которая тем меньше, чем меньше `EnergyConsumption`, и тем меньше, чем больше `CurrentEnergyAmount` и т. д. Причём если `EnergyConsumption` намного меньше, а `CurrentEnergyAmount` ненамного больше, то результат всё равно намного меньше. Из этих соображений оно и подбиралось.

Comment: Это чисто логически Вы додумались, или Вы использовали готовые знание из математики? Я год назад с этим сталкивался (там было два элемента в обьекте, как в примере), так вот я накатывал строчек так 25 на это решение (сначала сортировал по-минимум, потом искал максимум, потом меньший за максимум и тд, вообщем как-то так - уже не помню).

Comment: @nullptr: Ну, это скорее знания из математики, чем логика. Для логического мышления сегодня уже слишком поздно :-)

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться сортировкой, но о скорости работы сказать не берусь:

```
var result = (from station in stations
              orderby station.EnergyConsumption ascending,
                      station.CurrentEnergyAmount descending, 
                      station.NumRobotsNearStation descending, 
                      station.NumStationsAround ascending
              select station).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Если сортировка ленивая, будет быстро, по идее.

Comment: нет, эта штука с linq-запросом. Я простестировал на нескольких вхоных данных - оно дает не те результаты, которые нужно

Comment: @nullptr: Все зависит от постановки задачи. Первоначально Вы не дали всех необходимых деталей. Думаю ответ @VladD подходит.

Comment: Павел Азанов, спасибо. Ваш linq тоже мне пригодился

Answer (score 0):

Есть, и далеко не одно. Наилучшей для данного способа будет, на мой взгляд, LINQ-конструкция [FROM->SELECT->WHERE](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WhereLinq06202007094527AM/WhereLinq.aspx)